# How to make the transition to another section of a same page through clicking anchor tag (<a>) smoother in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

### Context

I have only been able to make an instant jump to another section without transition. Here is how I do that:

```
<a href="#go_middle">Go Middle</a>

<div id="go_middle">Hello There</div>
```

### Desired Result

I want to have transition effect, so it doesn't just instantly jump to the section, but rather a slower jump through another section of the page if there are any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your CSS to the appropriate class or id.

```
.scroll-div {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

You can also add it to the HTML tag directly.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

This will make the page scroll smoothly to the right section, without jumps.